# Sequence of Method calls : Design Pattern / OO Design

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

**Problem**

I am working on a UI framework which needs the methods and the page objects to be called dynamically in a sequence based on the input sequence. I mainly want to substitute the Switch / If else with a better OO way to make it easier for extension

All the pages extend a Base Abstract class and the methods extend another base Action class. I have annotations to identify classes and the methods. I need to build a list of methods which will be invoked by the framework in the same order for each test case.

I am using BDD for the input i.e.

Scenario : Test the transaction successful page

1. Given user logsin
2. And performs some actions
3. Then the transaction successful page is displayed

So, each step is mapped to a Action class which performs a set of Actions. I am using annotations to find the Action class.

```
//Sample JBehave Steps Pojo
@Given
public void login(String user)
{
 //Action to be performed is Login. Search for the Login Action class

}

@And
public void performSomeAction(String action , String component)    
{
Find the class representing this action
}


//Page Objects
ClassMap(name="loginPage")
public class LoginPage extend Page
  {

    MethodMap(action="test"  , component="test")
    public BaseStep login extends BaseStep
    {
       // returns a login step
    }

  }

    //Building the method sequence
    //Now each Test Step is mapped to a class
    for(Action : Actions to be performed)
    {
     //Check if the action / component maps to a method and a class
    switch(action)
   {
      case VERIFY:
         //Invoke the Method Verify
      case LOAD :
         //Invoke the Method Load
      case ACTION1 :
         //Perform some action
   }
```

I am looking for a design pattern to implement the same without using switch else. A good design pattern which would fit in is what I would be looking at.

Comment: [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is likely what you want. Create an interface `Action` with a `do()/execute()` method.  Create an implementation for each action you want (ie: `VerifyAction`, `LoadAction`, etc.).  Then, the entire switch statement is replaced with `action.do()`.

Comment: But how would I invoke a particular action. Should I have a factory method to get the objects? Like if it is a VerifyAction, how would I get the VerifyAction class?

Comment: There's multiple ways you can handle it.  In general, you don't want to expose internal classes outside of the area that contains them; anything outside of the "Action" package should only know they are dealing with `Action` objects, and not care about the specific implementations.  However, on some level, you need to define "what" you are creating.  [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is a traditional example on this front, but you could just as easily put a `public static Action makeVerifyAction()` method in your `Action` abstract class.

Comment: Be warned that the above has the flaw of giving each implementation of `Action` the `makeX()` actions, when really you're moreso just looking to use them in a static nature from the base class.  A better approach would be to leave `Action` as an interface instead of an abstract class, and have an `ActionBuilder` class which handles the building of the action implementations (but only returns `Action`).  Your interface to your action package is then the `Action` interface and the `ActionBuilder` class.